# Run windows vm with the lowest amount of ram possble

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-machine

So i want to run 5 windows 11 (Win 10 is ok too) vms with the lowest amount of ram possible.
Curently every vm has 1GB of ram, but i am trying to save as much ram as possible, how do i do that?

I am currently running windows 11 lite (modified version of windows 11)
Any tips?

These vms run software that collect you data, and sell it for money.

Edit : Thanks for the answers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the significance of that last sentence - do you mean you're running apps that make **you** money, or that you're trying to prevent other people making money out of your application usage? It does make the entire question feel like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: i am using apps like honeygain, that sell you data and then pay you

Comment: So i only have 5.69GB of ram and i am trying to save as much of it as possible for other vms, so i am looking for ways to lower ram usage on windows as much as possible.

Comment: 5 machines in 6 GB of memory total stand a good chance of not even starting.

Comment: The minimum amount of memory required for Windows 10 and Windows 11 is more than 1 GB. There is no way around that requirement

Comment: @i_Blaze - I have been editing my answer as we go along to help you and others.

Comment: Then if you're actually using this structure to make money - buy more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

For a modern machine to run smoothly as a virtual machine requires about 3 GB of memory (more if doing a lot of work) and 1 CPU with 2 cores.

This is a modest assignment of resources for an average workload.

I have 3 machines running, all smoothly, each with 3 GB and 2 processors (1 CPU, 2 cores).

The host (Windows 10) has 4 to 5 GB for a normal workload.

All is fast and smooth.

1 GB is likely too little (in my opinion), but you would have to experiment in your particular situation. Look at the total amount of memory you have, try 1 machine with 2 GB, see if it works, try 2 machines, and so on.

Modern operating systems mandate minimums for memory (usually 1 GB) to run, although 1 GB is most often too little. You can try retired operating systems (like Windows 7) to experiment with less memory.

5 machines and host likely needs a 32 GB host machine so that the host has sufficient resources to work properly.

**Summary after numerous comments:**

1. Modern operating system require minimum 1 GB of memory and will not do well with that. More is needed. 5 Windows 10 machines need about 15 GB.
2. Older operating systems (Windows 7 and older Linux) may work with more limited memory.
3. An underpowered machine (as appears to be here) with 5 VMs will grind to a whimpering halt (been there, done that).
4. For a business (done that) you need a computer powerful enough to serve your customers.

Comment: The vms dont need to run smoothly at all, they just have to boot up in 5-10minutes, and be somewhat usable, i dont use them they are just idle all of the time

Comment: You will have to experiment. There is no hard minimum standard. What I outlined above is a reasonable assignment of resources to work. Lower than that, you need to try and see.  By "smoothly" I meant run all the time without serious hangups.

Comment: @John - Yes; There actually is a hard minimum on the amount of system memory

Comment: Yes, for 10 / 11 1 GB minimum. There are other machines which can be used which was the intent of my comment.

Comment: I have an old Dell D-830 laptop, Core 2 Duo, 2GB RAM, and it runs Windows 10 Pro 64 bit OK for routine tasks and doesn't seem too sluggish. On my desktop PC, i7-4790, 16 GB RAM, if I run a VMware VM of that Windows version with 2 cores, 2 GB RAM, it runs like a stone dog.

Comment: no i am not doing this for a business, its my hobby

Comment: My error on that issue. Nonetheless, I have given you a very complete answer to your VM issue.